# Strong elements become italic

Tags: css, html, dreamweaver

I am supposed to "add a new rule so that strong elements in the html file are displayed italic"
This is my css:

```
body{
    font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;

}

h1{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

h2{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: georgia;

}

dt{
    font-weight: bold;
}

strong{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

I tried using `bold{ }` or `strong{ }` non of them working properly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strong{
    font-style: italic;
}`
   works for me...[here is the JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pok62unp/)...

Comment: What you have is supposed to work, please show your html where is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font-style of strong and b can be styled in CSS.

```
b { 
    font-style: italic;
} 

strong {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

This CSS does what you want.

See the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/tdmjb4b7/

Answer (score 0):

try this may help you

```
 dt, strong, b, h1, h2
 {
     font-style: italic;
 }
```